# Automorphism of the unit disk that fixes a point

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following question:
For each $b \in \mathbb{D}$, construct an automorphism $\phi$ of the unit disk that is not the identity map such that $\phi(b)=b$.

I know that all automorphisms of the disk must have the form $e^{i\theta}\left(\frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}\right)$ where $a \in \mathbb{D}$. The only map that I can see would fix $b$ is just a rotation by some multiple of $2\pi$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Using the automorphism $\phi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ mapping $a$ to $0$, consider $\phi_a^{-1} \circ (e^{i\theta} \mathrm{id}) \circ \phi_a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $b \ne 0$ as otherwise problem trivial.

Take $\psi_1(z)=\frac{z+b}{1+\bar b z}$. Clearly $\psi_1(0)=b$. Now take $\psi_2(z)=\alpha\frac{z-b}{1-\bar b z}, |\alpha|=1, \alpha \ne 1$. Clearly $\psi_2(b)=0$ so $\phi=\psi_1 \circ \psi_2$ satisfies $\phi(b)=b$

Since $\psi_2(0)=-\alpha b \ne -b$, $\phi(0) \ne 0$ so $\phi$ is not the identity