# Elementary proof that a function is a conformal automorphism of the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I would like to show that the function

$$f=\frac{c-z}{1-\bar c z}$$

with $|c| < 1$ is holomorphic and an automorphism from the complex disk $\{z: |z|<1\}$ to itself? I'm looking for an elementary proof of this (e.g without using that we can characterize the rotations of the unit disk as in [Automorphism of the unit disk that fixes a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744092/automorphism-of-the-unit-disk-that-fixes-a-point))

Answer (score 1):

The complex conjugate on the unit circle $z=  e^{i \phi}$ is the inverse

$$\frac{e^{i \theta } r-e^{i \phi }}{1-r e^{i \phi -i \theta }}\cdot \frac{e^{-i \theta } r-e^{-i \phi }}{1-r e^{i \theta -i \phi }}=\frac{\left(e^{i \theta } r-e^{i \phi }\right) \left(e^{-i \theta } r-e^{-i \phi }\right)}{\left(1-r e^{i \phi -i \theta }\right) \left(1-r e^{i \theta -i \phi }\right)}=\frac{r^2 +1 -r e^{i (\theta -\phi )}-r e^{i (\phi -\theta )}}{r^2 +1 -r e^{i (\theta -\phi )} -r e^{i (\phi -\theta )}}$$

It follows that the unit circle is mapped onto itself. Since $z=0$ maps to $c,|c|<1$ the inner maps to the inner. Conformality is confirmed by the real 2d Jacobian, but that identical to independence of the map wrt $\overline z.$

Comment: Thanks, but this shows $f_c(z)^{-1} = f_{\bar c}(\bar z)$ which shows $f_c$ is one to one. How does it follow that $f_c$ is also onto?